# Element appended to a linked list appears to change after being appended

Tags: c, pointers, struct, linked-list

My code (written in C) has a section where it is given a linked list and an item. The item is appended to the linked list, and I check for the value of the item before and after it is appended.

It displays some weird behaviors because the second attempt of appending appears to change the element passed after it has been appended to the list.

Part of code which calls the append function:

There are two cases: In the first(breaks==NULL), the list is empty. In the second, it is not.

```
  if (breaks == NULL){
      breaks = createNode(breakstart, breakend);
      printf("Headbreaks info:\n");
      printf("Next: %p\n", breaks -> next);
      head = breaks;
      appendToList(schedule, breaks); //append the break found to schedule list
      printf("\nBreaks info after append:\n");
      printf("Next: %p \n", breaks -> next);
    } else {
      breaks -> next = createNode(breakstart, breakend);
      breaks = breaks -> next;
      printf("Breaks info:\n");
      printf("Next: %p \n", breaks -> next);
      appendToList(schedule, breaks); //append the break found to schedule list
      printf("\nBreaks info after append:\n");
      printf("Next: %p \n", breaks -> next);
      i++;
    }
```

Append function: Travels to the end of list and appends item to it. Also has some print functions for some amateur debugging.

```
void appendToList(timeblock *list, timeblock* item){
  while (list -> next != NULL){
    printf("(%d - %d)", list -> start, list -> end);
    list = list -> next;
  }
  printf("\nAppend to: (%d - %d)", list -> start, list -> end);
  list -> next = item;
}
```

Node creation:

```
timeblock* createNode(int start, int end){
  timeblock *new = malloc(sizeof(timeblock));
  new -> start = start;
  new -> end = end;
  new -> next = NULL;
  return new;
}
```

Output snippet:

```
Headbreaks info:
Next : 00000000
Headbreaks info after append:
Next : 00000000

Breaks info:
Next : 00000000
Breaks info after append:
Next : 00322438 //I expected it to be null!
```

Comment: In the first block of the code it is a bit unclear what the role of `breaks` is. Apparently there are two cases; in the first one,`breaks` is assigned a new node, while in the second one, `breaks` already has a successor, which is then assigned a new node, which finally is then appended to the list. Furthermore, the function `appendToList` inserts `item` at the end of the list, but does not set `item->next` to `null`, which however is done by `createNode`; is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I'll add that in the original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my understanding, in the second case of the first code snippet the part

```
breaks -> next = createNode(breakstart, breakend);
breaks = breaks -> next;
// some debug code
appendToList(schedule, breaks);
```

inserts a node into the list which is already inserted by having its predecessor pointing to it.

Comment: Oh, I get it now. Does that mean I was accidentally copying more elements to the schedule list than I intended?

Would adding a copy of breaks, instead of breaks itself, be the solution?

Comment: I can't really tell from the snippets you have posted; it seems inconsistent to me that the implementation accesses the pointers in the list directly on one hand, but on the other hand uses an abstraction like `appendToList`.

Comment: Using a copy worked. I suspected that my previous implementation was appending lists instead of elements. This caused some really odd behavior I didn't bother examining.